# Is there something like PHP ob_start for C?

Tags: c

I have a simple gateway listener which generates a log at the screen output via printf. I would like to record it so I can insert it in a mysql table.

```
printf("\nPacket received!! Decoding...");
```

I wonder if there is any fast way to do this is C.

In case there is, could I get both outputs at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any function that does output buffering in C. But you can simulate one easily like:

```
char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = ""; // that buffers your output.
char temp[SOME_SUITABLE_MAX];
```

now everytime you are using `printf`, use a `sprintf` as follows:

```
sprintf(temp,"\nPacket received!! Decoding...");
```

and them append this string to the buffer

```
strcat(buffer,temp);
```

keep doing the `sprintf` followed by `strcat` for every message you want to buffer and once done buffer will have the buffered output.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for provided I'll save the log in a mysql database. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "record it" you mean you want to write it to a file, then yes, it's pretty easy. Unix has had a `tee` utility for years that would let you do something like:

```
gateway_listener | tee record_file
```

If you're running on a system that doesn't provide a `tee` by default, it should be pretty easy to find or compile one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *outfile;
    int c;

    if ( argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: tee <out_file>\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (NULL == (outfile = fopen(argv[1], "w"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (EOF != (c=getchar())) {
        putc(c, outfile);
        putchar(c);
    }

    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well redirecting the output to a file seems trivial, but what I really needed is to save the output to a mysql table. Thanks for your input and for custom tee which I'll take care of :D